# Can't overwrite external stylesheet property with inline style in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a custom `TextInput` component that takes in two stylesheets and appends any inline styles afterwards and passes those to the `TextInput` `style` property:

```
class WSTextInput extends React.Component<TextInputProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.defaultText, styles.defaultTextInput, this.props.style] as StyleProp<TextStyle>}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

These are the stylesheets it uses:

```
 defaultText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'cardenio-modern'
  },
  defaultTextInput: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    margin: 10
  }
```

The code works fine so as long as `this.props.style` does not attempt to overwrite any of the existing properties in `defaultText` or `defaultTextInput`.

When I do try to do so, e.g. with this element (note that `styles.defaultTextInput`'s `borderBottomWidth` and `backgroundColor` are overwritten):

```
<WSTextInput style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
            editable={false}
            value={this.state.total.toString()}
          />
```

Then this is the result:

[image]

The top right element is a `WSTextInput` rendering correctly without inline overrides; the bottom right element is a `WSTextInput` with the above inline overrides rendering incorrectly.

When I open `reactnative-tools` and inspect the element tree, I see this for the top right element:

[image]

And this for the bottom right element:

[image]

So it seems that for the bottom right element, the inline style survives, but both stylesheets are lost.

I have tried different ways of coalescing the properties in `WSTextInput.render`, e.g. using `Object.assign` or the spread operator, but the result is the same. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused what you're looking to do. Should this component allow style to be overridden by props? Should it be a subset of the style props?

Comment: I would like it to be a union of both stylesheets and whatever is specified inline (with inline overwriting anything in the stylesheet).

Comment: Sorry if what I'm intending isn't clearer--still new to React/React Native. The docs seem to state that the correct pattern for setting "defaults" for <Text>, <View> etc. is to create your own component <MyText>, <MyView> that specifies a style object or a stylesheet. But I would like to use the inline `style` prop to override that default stylesheet occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not exactly clear on what the desired outcome is because it's not great to not allow the font size and some others to not be overridden. But, I think this is just as simple as moving the props to the first arg so they are overridden by yours.

```js
    render() {
     const {style, ...theRest} = this.props;
      return (
        <TextInput
        {...this.props}
          style={[styles.defaultText, styles.defaultTextInput] as StyleProp<TextStyle>}
         />
      );
    }
```

For more control try removing the style from the props and passing it where desired in the style props so font is overridden but other stuff isn't.

```js
    render() {
     const {style, ...theRest} = this.props;
      return (
        <TextInput
          style={[styles.defaultText, style, styles.defaultTextInput] as StyleProp<TextStyle>}
          {...theRest}
        />
      );
    }
```

Finally, you can explicitly remove the ones you don't want overridden thru deconstruction and pass thru anything else.

```js
const {style, ...theRest} = this.props;
const {backgroundColor, borderBottomWidth, ...theRestOfStyle} = style;
```

Then use it in your style:

```js
<TextInput
        style={[styles.defaultText, styles.defaultTextInput, theRestOfStyle] as StyleProp<TextStyle>}
{...theRest}
      />
```

Comment: Okay, so the first option caused the inline style to have no effect, but the second option with the ordering `[styles.defaultText, styles.defaultTextInput, style]` worked as intended. Seems that I do have to explicitly pluck `style` from props in this scenario. Thanks!